# Tourgenerierung vs. Tourengenerierung

Tags: compound, word-formation

Wie schreibt man richtig

> Tourgenerierung

oder

> Tourengenerierung?

Jedes mal wenn ich *Tour…* schreibe, meckert mein Word 2010. Wenn ich aber auf *Touren…* umschreibe, dann scheint alles OK zu sein. Bei *Tourengenerierung* habe ich aber kein gutes Gefühl…

Ist es vielleicht eine Art Ausnahme wie bei Student -> Studenten?

Comment: Es erscheint mir schon per se komisch, eine Tour *generieren* zu wollen. Was möchtest du ausdrücken?

Comment: In jedem Fall ist es auch keine Frage der Rechtschreibung, sondern der Wortbildung. Wenn man _Tourengenerierung_ sagt, schreibt man auch _Tourengenerierung_, und wenn man _Tourgenerierung_ sagt, dann _Tourgenerierung_. Aber mir ist auch nicht klar, worum es da geht. Kommt der Motor auf Touren? Werden Reisen für Touristen geplant?

Comment: Pflegetouren. Patient A, dann Patient B usw. daraus wird eine Tour generiert. Wieso noch mal erscheint das per se komisch?

Comment: "Generierung" wäre für mich deswegen nicht erste Wahl, weil die Wege ja schon existieren und auch die gewählte Tour sicher schon einmal jemand eingeschlagen hat; treffender wäre *Auswahl*. Der klassische Begriff ist m. E. *Routenplanung*; da muss auch zweifelsfrei der Plural stehen.

Comment: @guidot `en` bildet hier keinen Plural, es ist ein sog. Fugenlaut, siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: Ich bleibe bei der Meinung, dass das Wort schlecht gewählt ist und ohne Zusammenhang nicht verständlich ist; ich würde also eher etwas in Richtung *Tourenauswahl* oder *Patientenreihenfolge* sagen. Für den Fall, dass das Wort unerlässlich ist, gilt Wolfs Antwort und *Tourengenerierung* ist wahrscheinlich die bessere Wahl (wobei ich *Tourgenerierung* nicht als falsch werten würde).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Tourengenerierung* bedeutet, dass *eine* Tour generiert wird, genau wie bei der *Routenplanung* *eine* Route geplant wird. Das `en` hinter Tour bzw. `n` hinter Route ist ein [Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut), der die Aussprache erleichtert. Es handelt sich also nicht um Mehrzahlformen, die hier mit der Planung bzw. Generierung verknüpft werden.

Nun könnte man sich fragen, wie es heißt, wenn man mehrere Routen plant. Soweit ich weiß, gibt es dafür im Deutschen keine eigenen Wörter. Wenn zwei Leute ihren Geburtstag gemeinsam feiern, gibt es trotzdem keine "Geburtstagefeier" - auch wenn vermutlich jeder Deutsche das verstehen würde.

Comment: genau das wollte ich wissen. danke!

Comment: Doch, gibt es: Tourengenerierung*en*, wie auch Geburtstagsfeier*n* ;)

Comment: Dennoch Vorsicht, was Rechtschreibprüfungen betrifft, man weiß nie, was die wirklich begreifen, gerade bei zusammengesetzten Wörtern erlebe ich Fehlschläge ohne Ende. Im Deutschen steht es jedem Sprecher (oder Schreiber) im Prinzip jederzeit frei, selbst Wörter zusammenzusetzen, deshalb zählt zu den "morphologisch reichhaltigen" Sprachen, für solche Sprachen wurde [Hunspell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell) entwickelt, das ich von meiner Firefox-Rechtschreibprüfung her kenne. Ist das (oder etwas ähnliches) auch in Word 2010 enthalten?

Comment: @Jan Klar gibt es Mehrzahlen zusammengesetzter Wörter, ich hatte nicht vor, das in Abrede zu stellen. Eine Funktion zur "Routenplanung" kann man natürlich für all seine "Routenplanungen" benutzen ;-)